# How should I structure my database to stop having so many tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Ok so i have a website in progress that will allow users to build routines using a set list of exercises provided. They can add a number of exercises to a routine which they will create and title themselves.

So i'm thinking i should have a user table.
Each user will have a number of routines.
Each routine will have a number of exercises.

Therefore I will have 3 tables: user, routines, and exercises

BUT

How can i link the 'routines' and 'exercises', because 'routines' is going to have to be more than one table, because if you imagine a user creates "biceps" routine and fills it with exercises. Then he creates "triceps" and fills it with exercises. He will then have to have two routine tables called 'biceps' and 'triceps'.

So how can I structure my database to accommodate this?

bearing in mind each user has a unique ID
Every exercise has a unique ID
and Every Routine has a unique ID.

Comment: Apologies for the crap title, loads were taken, just had to make it unique.

Comment: Is there a difference between 'biceps' and 'triceps' routines, in a sense that they'll need different fields in the database? Also, can routines ever be shared between multiple users (or they are always "private" to a specific user)?

Comment: the difference is whatever the user makes it, they add the exercises to the routines they create. And yes, routines are private to each user because they create them. They are not shared.

Comment: Let's forget about exercises for the moment and concentrate on routines alone: you don't actually need different database **fields** for 'biceps' vs. 'triceps', correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table users(
userid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname char(30) not null,
lastname char(30) not null
);

create table routines(
rid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
userid int not null,
rname char(30) not null
);

create table execises(
eid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
rid int not null,
ename char(30) not null
);
```

Comment: `VARCHAR`s would probably be more appropriate than `CHAR(30)`s.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to have two `routines` tables.
You want **one** `routines` table, plus an `exercises` table that references the `routines` table.

Depending on whether one routine is the same for all users, or whether each user can have his own version of the "biceps" routine, maybe you need one more table.
Take a look at the examples below!

---

**Example 1 (each user can have his own "biceps" routine):**

Users table:

```
UserId  Name
----------------
1       Joe
2       Bill
```

Routines table:

```
RoutineId   Name     UserId
-------------------------------
1           biceps   1
2           biceps   2
```

Exercises table:

```
ExerciseId    RoutineId  Name
--------------------------------------------------------
1             1          first exercise of routine 1
2             1          second exercise of routine 1
3             2          first exercise of routine 2
4             2          second exercise of routine 2
```

---

**Example 2 (there is only one "biceps" routine, and it's the same for all users):**

Users table:

```
UserId  Name
----------------
1       Joe
2       Bill
```

Routines table:

```
RoutineId   Name  
------------------
1           biceps
```

Users <--> Routines link table:

```
UserId   RoutineId
--------------------
1        1
2        1
```

Exercises table:

```
ExerciseId    RoutineId  Name
--------------------------------------------------------
1             1          first exercise of routine 1
2             1          second exercise of routine 1
```

---

**EDIT:**

You said:

> And yes, routines are private to each user because they create them. They are not shared

and:

> Each exercise should be able to be used more than once. I.e i might have a 'pull ups' exercise in my "back workout" routine, and my "arm workout" routine

**Final Solution:**

Users table:

```
UserId  Name
----------------
1       Joe
2       Bill
```

Routines table:

```
RoutineId   Name                    UserId
-----------------------------------------------------
1           Joe's back workout      1
2           Joe's arm workout       1
3           Bills's back workout    2
```

"global" Exercises table:

```
ExerciseId    Name
--------------------------------------------------------
1             pull up
2             whatever
```

Routines <--> Exercises link table:

```
RoutineId  ExerciseId
----------------------------------
1          2
2          1
3          1
```

That way, the "pull up" exercise is in Joe's arm workout (routine 2) and Bills's back workout (routine 3), but not in Joe's back workout (routine 1).
The "whatever" routine is in Joe's back workout (routine 1) only.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I think you have routines and exercises reversed.  A routine consists of several exercises.

Comment: Yes, I know that a routine consists of several exercises - so do the routines in my examples.

Comment: One other thing to consider would be making the routines-exercises relationship many-many, too.  This would allow for exercises to be used in multiple routines and allow easier building of routines by being able to reuse exercises.

Comment: Thank you. I have a huge exercise database filled with about 200 different exercises. 

Each exercise should be able to be used more than once. I.e i might have a 'pull ups' exercise in my "back workout" routine, and my "arm workout" routine.

Comment: @LouisAnderson: okay, check out my answer again. I just edited it!

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted thank you :) 
BUT
Am I just being stupid here? Will each routine be able to store multiple exercises in it?
I suck at relational databases as you can see, does the SQL that was posted match your final answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is in the `Routines <--> Exercises` table - you can add more rows with the same `RoutineId` and different `ExerciseIds`. For example, a row with `RoutineId` = 1 and `ExerciseId` = 1 would add the "pull up" exercise to the "Joe's back workout" routine.

Comment: The primary key of the table would be a combination of both columns, so it's not possible to store the exact same combination twice.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Christian and speedy replies! great feedback.

Comment: @LouisAnderson: If I provided great feedback, then why did you accept the other answer which does not do what you want? (the exercises there are tied to one routine and can't be used more than once)